# Combine column results in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I have a functionality where user can select `table(only one at a time)` and based on that `table columns` will appear. User can select multiple columns so what I want is,when user selects column(s) then it should return the result of selected columns. Now as per my table if user selects `Colum_1 which has unique values` then I'll allow user to select that but if user selects `Column_2` I'll prompt the message by saying that 'Select another column or more than one', and then in background I'll create combination for those selected columns.

Example:

```
Table name = `TestTable` 

Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
-------- -------- --------
    1        1       ab
    2        2       bc
    3        1       bc
```

Expected results:

```
Column_1 = 1 2 3
Column_1, Column_2 = 1 1, 2 2, 3 1 (combination of two columns)
Column_1, Column_2, Column_3 = 1 1 ab, 2 2 bc, 3 1 bc (combination of three columns)
```

I've tried a query but it is useful for one column name only. I'm not sure if user selects multiple columns then how to handle that.

My query:

```
declare @colCount bigint, @uniqColCount bigint, @result nvarchar(max)

select @colCount = count(Column_1) from TestTable
select @uniqColCount = count(distinct Column_1) from TestTable

    if(@colCount = @uniqColCount)
     begin
        set @result = (select Column_1 from TestTable)
        print @result
     end
    else
        print 'false'
```

I need to achieve `for-each` kind of logic in `SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a While condition to solve this. Here is a reference for more details.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms178642.aspx